# Laravel 9 upgrade giving htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 _ given

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, upgrade, laravel-9

I'm having a not-so-fun time of upgrading a Laravel 8 project to Laravel 9 and thought I had finally got it working because the login and dashboard display correctly. Navigating to any of my other views though gives:

> htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, _
> given in `public/index.php: 52` (`$request = Request::capture()`)

It seems loads of people get a different variant of this error ("array given") but not this specifically.

I was getting errors on double underscores previously during the upgrade process because I had a lot of that in my views (e.g. `{{ __('Dashboard') }}`) just from the Laravel default view content. So I stripped out all the double underscores. Not sure if this is related to that, but I don't understand why dashboard works but every other view doesn't?

Update: disregard - this was due to my routes being lost in the move to v9. I had copied them over but I guess one of the multitude of various artisan and other commands I ran afterwards reset it to the default routes file (the built-in Laravel `404.blade.php` contained the double underscores and that's what it was trying to load).

Answer (score 0):

I might think it is related but not sure as laravel-9 have placed lang directly under root folder from resources/lang. Did you look into this?

Comment: Well it looks like in the process of my update I ended with `lang` in both locations. I tried renaming them individually though and then even renamed them both and nothing had any effect on the error I'm getting.

Comment: Aha! There were underscores in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/404.blade.php` so I removed those and now have a "working 404" page. So I guess my routing got broken in the upgrade. I'll update the question.

Comment: OK there it is - my routes/web.php is missing all my routes! Restored from pre-update version and it's all good :-)